# Perl regular expression to match embedded tag once

Tags: regex, perl

I have some text which I would like to match based on tag only appears once.
Text is as below (some random chars can contain anything except for tags):

```
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
```

The match I want is: to match tag3 within tag2 which only appears once.

For example:

```
<tag2><tag3>something</tag3></tag2> is matched
<tag2><tag3>something</tag3><tag3>something</tag3></tag2> isn't matched
```

Based on above text, the expected output is: line 2 and 5.

The regex I tried (didn't work):

```
<tag2><tag3>(.*)?</tag3></tag2>
<tag2><tag3>(.*){1}</tag3></tag2>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Is this XML, HTML or something that just looks like it? The duplicate may be valid, but there are cases where a pragmatic regex is fine.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, the tags can be any special characters, so it is a regex question to me. This is XML btw. :)

Comment: Also, are we talking PCRE regex, or do you have an actual Perl program?

Comment: It does matter. `XML` is a contextual language. Regex cannot do context. therefore it's a terrible solution.

Comment: Thanks all above! simbabque has the right answer.

Comment: @Sobrique if it's a pattern as simple as this, and the format of the input file is always the same, a regex-based solution is totally fine in my opinion. Sometimes it's ok to be pragmatic.

Comment: If it were not trivial to parse as `XML` using `xpath` I might agree. As is, this is building brittle code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex didn't work because you were allowing everything (`.`) in your capture group. That is very greedy and will go as far as possible and only stop at the last `</tag3>`. If you want to match only stuff that cannot inlcude tags, you need to match anything but an opening tag token.

```
m{<tag2><tag3>([^<]+)</tag3></tag2>}g
```

Try it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yB7zM4/1).

Comment: Cheers, @simbabque, you are absolutely right. And I also worked out a solution: <tag2><tag3>((?!tag).)*<\/tag3><\/tag2>

Answer (score 4):

I would urge you not to use regular expressions to manipulate XML - ever. Regular expressions cannot handle a contextual language like XML, and as a result you build brittle code - that a perfectly valid alteration to XML format (such as whitespacing) might break.

So instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->parse( \*DATA );

foreach my $element ( $twig->get_xpath('//tag2') ) {
   if ( scalar $element->children('tag3') == 1 ) {
      $element->print;
      print "\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
<root>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
<tag1><tag2><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1>
</root>
```

This will handle XML formatted as you have, but also just on a single line. Or like this:

```
<root>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
      <tag3>Some randome chars</tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
</root>
```

Or like this:

```
<root
><tag1
><tag2
><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1><tag1
><tag2
><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1><tag1
><tag2
><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1><tag1
><tag2
><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1><tag1
><tag2
><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1><tag1
><tag2
><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1><tag1
><tag2
><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1><tag1
><tag2
><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3><tag3
>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2></tag1></root>
```

Which are semantically identical to yours.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique, this may also work, but my real case was a bit complicated and it wasn't some kind translated XML mapping.

Comment: You said in the comments that you were working with XML. If you are, then as complication increases, the case for an XML parser does too.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML aware tool. I tried the following in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
ls //tag2[1=count(tag3)]
```

After adding line numbers to the tag2's, I got

```
<tag2>2<tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2>
<tag2>5<tag3>Some randome chars</tag3></tag2>
```